# Interpreting Python T-Test output

Tags: python, t-test

I am doing a two-sample student t-test ($\alpha = 0.05$)  with the null hypothesis being the mean of group 1 is $\leq$ mean of group 2, and the alternate being, mean of group 1 > mean of group 2.

After running the code that does the test in python (stats.ttest) i get a test statistic of -2.83 and a p value of 0.00465. I understand that this p-value is for a two tail test thus i was wondering how to turn this into a 1-tail p-value (do i simple divide by 2 or do i do 1-(p/2)) and whether or not i reject the Null in this case?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure, what stats.ttest is calculating. But if the sample mean of group 1 ≤ the sample mean of group 2, your $p$-value would be $1-p/2$ (I would think this is what it calculates). The null hypothesis couldn't be rejected, since it looks the other way around (note that this can't be claimed any more - only if you would have chosen a two-sided $t$-test).

If the sample mean of group 1 > the sample mean of group 2, you could divide it by 2 and the null hypothesis could be rejected.

Please note that you should always fix your hypothesis (and whether you want to use a one-sided and in which direction or two-sided test) before the experiment and not after looking at the data.

Comment: What do you mean by you're not sure what stats.ttest is calculating? In python you input your group 1 and group 2 sampled data into stats.ttest() and it gives an output which is the Student t-test t-stat and the 2-tail p-value. 

My confusion was how to transform this 2-tail p-value into a 1-tail p-value (since my hypothesis is one-sided) and then make a conclusion as to whether or not to reject the null.

Comment: Could you show me a reference to stats.ttest?

Comment: Because it's not always clear what group 1 and what group 2 means. Also if you could tell me the sample means of your data, I would be sure what python is doing and could answer your question.

Comment: Reference: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html

My group 1 sample mean = 0.368622
My Group 2 sample mean = 1.422089

Comment: So there is no evidence that group mean 1 > group mean 2 (it seems more the other way around!), you have a p-value of 0.9976 and you can't reject the null hypothesis.